# Facing dbt source tag Issue

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I am Facing issue in the dbt run due source issue
Compilation Error
Model ‘model.project.stg_table’ (models/staging/stg_table.sql) depends on a source named ‘psa.emissionsbycountry’ which was not found

Models Path

```
model/
    staging/
           stg_table.sq [dbt model]
           schema.yml
```

**stg_table.sql**

```
{{
  config(
    materialized = 'view',
    )
}}

select * from {{ source('psa', 'emissionsbycountry') }}
```

**schema.yml**

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: EMISSIONSBYCOUNTRY
    database: DATABASE
    schema: PSA
    tables:
      - name: EMISSIONSBYCOUNTRY

    
models:
  - name: stg_table
```

In **dbt_profile.yml** define the schema

```
models:
  staging:
    +schema: psa
```

In the profile.yml
**the default schema is psa**

And Even in the Snowflake Environment table do exist

```
select * from database.psa.emissionsbycountry;
```

Is something am I missing here ?

Comment: Yes, you're missing a sources.yml (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/sources#declaring-a-source)

Comment: Thanks  for the help. 
It is was something related to source tag format. missing related to spacing I think soo.